# How to do an Arrhenius plot using excel-VBA? AKA: How to do a reciprocal x-axis in excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I want to write a program to transform temperature dependend data into an Arrhenius plot. An Arrhenius plot show the logarithm of a property that is thermally acitavted versus the reciprocal temperature aka 1/T. Now is 1/T something that most people are not used to. This is why most of the plot also contain the translation in temperature on a second axis. Usually on top of the graph. The output should look like this:

[image]

[Picture Source](http://blog.originlab.com/graphing/display-celsius-as-top-axis-in-arrhenius-plot)

The second axis is only for better readability and is corresponds to the primary axis with the relation:

```
primary=1/secondary 

secondary=1/primary
```

**What I am not able to do in excel-VBA (excel 2010) is the reciprocal second x-axis.** There is no predefined axis scaling like this. There is `xlScaleLinear` and `xlScaleLogarithmic` for the property `ScaleType` of an axis. Is there a way to do this?

A secondary problem is that this:

```
Dim CH As Chart

Set CH = Tabelle2.ChartObjects(1).Chart

CH.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

With CH
    .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlSecondary) = True
End With
```

Does not seem to work. Which means that a xyScatterplot does not seem to have a secondaryXaxis enabled.

I could try to add the lables and ticks myself using forms but this seems a little to much pain, I cannot be the only one who has encountered this problem.

- Problem 1: How to format an axis reciprocal (1/x)?
- Problem 1b: How to properly add a second x axis in a XYscatterplot?

Comment: Did you try to do it manually and record a macro to get an idea how the code could look like?

Comment: @PEH I tried that, problem is that I haven't managed to do it manually. There are some turtorials for later excel versions e.g. 2013 but in 2011 the turtorials do not sem to apply.

Comment: Well, if it is not possible manually then there is a high probability that there is no VBA solution too. I would always try to do a manual solution first, then it's much easier get it done in VBA. So if the actual question is, if this was possible in Excel 2011 (which is not a programming question in first place) and you don't get an answer here, then I suggest to try at [Stack Exchange: Superuser](https://superuser.com) to find out if it is possible at all. (If possible › Macro Recorder, if not possible › Upgrade Excel).

Comment: @PEH You mean there is no convenient solution to it. I could always just write a macro that inserts lineas and textfields to mimic an axis. This solves the problem but is a pain to do. But I will check out superuser for a solution thank you. I will link the superuser question when I am done.

Comment: I cannot tell if there is a convenient solution because I don't have an Excel 2010 to check it. Just wanted to leave that comment as follow up if you don't get any solution here. Since Microsoft's official mainstream support of Excel 2010 ended in October 2015 people who have that version will be getting rare. (Since you use an Excel version ending its life time (in 2020) it might be an additional reason to upgrade).

Comment: @PEH yeah I will probably get a more recent version of excel pretty soon but that is for my IT department to decide. We also run on winows 7 because of cost reasons, that will probably change soon too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by creating a fake axis using a series with data labels (inspired by https://peltiertech.com/secondary-axes-that-work-proportional-scales/):

[image]

Columns A and B are your data. Column C matches the X-ticks of your primary X-axis. Column D is `=1/C2` etc and column E is the y-axis maximum for your chart. Now simply create a new series of columns C and E, format it to have no line and in this case I chose the + marker but you can create your own vertical line marker if you want it to be exact. Then add data labels set to range column D.

I don't think you'll find another way to do it without this hack, but it's really not that hard and doesn't require VBA which is always a plus in terms of readability / audibility of your workbook.

Comment: I like this approach but to make the fake axis logarithmic (and make their ticks neither match the x-ticks nor match the data points) would be a bit tricky I think. For that additional data points are needed I think.

Comment: @Peh no it's easy, just apply whatever transformation you want to column C. I thought you wanted them to match, but it's an independent series so you can put them where ever you want and they need not be linearly spaced.

Comment: I guess the tricky part is figuring out the transformation such that a log spacing fits your range (2.5 - 4.0)...

Comment: He has also a [turtorial for the x-axis](https://peltiertech.com/reciprocal-chart-axis-scale/) one of the harder abuses of excel I have seen so far but hey it works!

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda I wish Microsoft would just make all the hacks he publishes features

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be to use the data labels to write the actual temperature to the data points:

[image]

Column C has the temperature in Celsius.

Since the Arrhenius plot is only defined as `ln(k)` against `1/T`, this would be a good option I think.